# Why does my decorator execute the code in this order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I have the following code and I have a hard time understanding why it prints the statements in the order it does.

```
def main():
    print('1')
    registry=[]

def register(func):
    print('2')
    registry.append(func)
    return func

@register
def f1():
    print('3')
print('4')
f1()
main()
```

This code prints:

```
1
2
4
3
```

But I'm wondering why it doesn't print:

```
1
2
3
4
```

when the `@register` is called I understand it that `register(f1)` is called, it prints `2` and then `f1` is returned. To me it seems like `3` should be printed next since `f1` is returned. But instead `f1` is not called until the very end `f1()` statement. Doesn't `return func` run the function it returns?

Comment: The code won't run as `registry` is local to `main()` function and is not defined in `register` decorator

Comment: "To me it seems like 3 should be printed next since f1 is returned" But `f1` is just _returned_; it is _not_ called. (But actually, for me it prints `2 4 3 1`)

Comment: Even if `registry` were a pre-defined global, the first value output would be 2, because `register` runs before `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equivalent code that *doesn't* use decorator syntax. Also, we make `registry` a pre-defined global so that the code actually runs.

```
registry = []

def main():
    print('1')
    #registry=[]

def register(func):
    print('2')
    registry.append(func)
    return func

def f1():
    print('3')

f1 = register(f1)
print('4')
f1()
main()
```

The first function that gets called is `register`, so the first value output is `2`. Next, `print('4')` outputs `4`. Third, `f1` is called and outputs `3`. Finally, `main` is called and outputs `1`.

`register` never *calls* `f1`; it simply adds it to the list `registry` and returns it.

Comment: So what is the return func statement used for if it doesn't run/call the function?

Comment: It returns the `function` object *itself* (so that it can be reassigned to the original name); see `f1 = register(f1)`.

Comment: There's really nothing that decorator syntax allows you to do that you couldn't do without it; it's purely a convenience.

Comment: Basically, using `@register` like this saves you from writing `registry.append(f1)` after defining `f1`. But by using a decorator, you have to ensure that the name `f1` actually refers to the defined function, which is why `register` has to return `f1` as well.